# Javascript change div color on click once for each

Tags: javascript, html

How would I change the colour of a divs background for multiple divs, but once. So if you click on div 1 the colour changes to blue, click on div 2 the div1 colour goes back to default and div2 goes to blue? Kind of how facebook chat tabs work with the top header

Comment: You mean you want to be able to 'select' one? Just have a css class for `.selected` and style it how you want. Then `onclick` of div, remove class from *all* divs, the add `selected` to the clicked div. Try it, if you get stuck then come back with code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_. Maybe you expected a free code writing service here?

Comment: I need it to be a javascript function so I can have it submit a "Seen" to the database

Comment: `onclick` is a javascript function, make it do whatever you want

Comment: Please take a minute and rethink what you want to do. Everything you need has already been answered or can be found through a simple search. Nobody will give you the code on a silver plate. Without a code you provide it is hard to tell what you want to do. However to give you a starting hint: You need to get all `DIVs` through a `querySelectorAll` function. After that iterate through them and set the colors. If you want to put the `seen-value` into a database you can easily use attributes for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do like that. Just add a class like "active" to the clicked element and remove it from others

```
var menu = document.querySelector("#menu");

for(var i = 0; i < menu.children.length; i++){
    menu.children[i].onclick = function (event){
    document.querySelector(".active").className = "";
    event.target.className = "active";
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jc61tgns/

Comment: Thank you so much! thats just what I wanted, don't know why someone down voted your answer as its perfect. Many thanks

Comment: is there anyway to have this working, but when all the items/divs have no preset active class?

Comment: You can change the line
**document.querySelector(".active").className = "";**
by
**var active = document.querySelector(".active");
if(active) active.className = "";**

it will works everytime :)

Answer (score -1):

What I would adivce you to do, is the following :

- create a CSS class, such as `.active { background-color: blue; }`
- use JavaScript to add/remove `.active` from divs.

For instance, in pure JavaScript :

```
const divs = document.querySelector('#root > div');

divs.on('click', function(e) {
    // Toggle off all divs.
    divs.forEach(d => d.classList.remove('active'));

    // Toggle on clicked div.
    e.target.classList.add('active');
});
```

Doc : [classtList](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

Cheers,
Guillaume.

Answer (score -2):

you can give a `id` to your `div` tag and create a `onclick` event like `<div id="div1" onclick="changebg()">` 
Inside changebg() you can write your code to change the background color